# Provide SFTP access to all users to mounted s3fs directory on EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, sftp, amazon-ec2

I have created 10 SFTP users on the EC2 instance and I am able to login to the server. I have an SSH key for all users for authentication instead of a password.

I am mounting the s3 bucket to one particular folder in Ubuntu user using the [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). I am able to mount it and access it using Ubuntu user. I want to make the mounted directory accessible to all 10 SFTP users.

I am mounting the s3 bucket using the below command

```
s3fs <s3_bucket_name> /home/ubuntu/s3bucket -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs,umask=002
```

I have tried adding the permissions below

```
sudo chown root:root /new/mount/point
sudo chmod 775 /new/mount/point
```

But the 10 users are not able to access the mounted s3 directory. The mounted directory is not getting listed.